# PowerShell turning an if else statement to a Foreach Loop

Tags: powershell, if-statement, foreach, scripting

I have a need to get rid of some users that do not exist in AD anymore but are still installed to an application.

I have a script which provides a list of users and assigns them to a variable. At the moment I want a list of users that do notexist. This works for a single user:

```
#One user in an Application 

$Users = $location.Users.FindAll() | where {$_.username -like "*johnsmith*"} | select username 

Username                                                                                                                                                                        
--------                                                                                                                                                                        

JohnSmith


#See if user exists in AD (Match Username with AD UserPrincipalName)

$users = $repository.Users.FindAll() |where {$_.username -like "*johnp*"} | select username 

$users2 = Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$($users.username)'" -Properties  LastLogonDate

if (!$users2 )
{
Write-Host "$users doesnt exist"
}

else
{
Write-Host "$users does exist"
}


> @{Username=JohnSmith} doesnt exist
```

Problem I am getting is feeding this to a foreach loop for multiple users in the variable. How can I put this to look through the object for each user and output the ones which do not exist?

```
#List of all users in Appication

$Users = $location.Users.FindAll() | select username 

Username                                                                                                                                                                        
--------                                                                                                                                                                        

JohnSmith
JohnSmith1
JohnSmith2
```

Tried this, but doesnt work, shows all users exist even though JohnSmith doesnt exist as above:

```
$users = $location.Users.FindAll() |select username 

$users2 = Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$($users.username)'"

foreach ($users2 in $users){
if (!$users2 )
 {
 write-host "$users2 doesnt exist"
}

else
{
write-host "$users2 does exist"
}
}

PS C:\>
@{Username=JohnSmith} does exist
@{Username=JohnSmith1} does exist
@{Username=JohnSmith2} does exist
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not tested but this should return a list of all application users that are not in AD:

```
$applicationUsers = $location.Users.FindAll() | select username 
$adUsers = Get-ADUser -filter * | select -ExpandProperty UserPrincipalName
$users = $applicationUsers | Where username -NotIn $adUsers
```

And you can iterate over them using:

```
$users | Foreach-Object { $_ }
```

Comment: `Get-ADUser -filter *` is a very bad practice. Cant imagine how long will this take to complete in my AD with OVER NINE THOUSAND (seriously) user-type objects. You must specify some criteria, otherwise it can take too long to retrieve all user objects. I just checked: 2mins 15 secs and ~500mb of my RAM.

Comment: @n01d This is not bad practice by itself. It depends on his environment which we don't know so Im not able to give him the right criteria to improve the performance if needed overall.

Comment: @Martin Brandl, in my opinion it's better to search for every single user in AD than retrieve entire AD. In any case. Except you have ~100 user objects in directory. But since we don't know the environment it's not the reason to give advices like this. Just my opinion based on my personal practice.

Comment: @n01d Still, its depending on his environment and due to his answer this solution seems like to fit perfect for him thus I don't understand the downvote. Also im sure someone using this cmdlet is aware of the `-filter` parameter and is able to adopt it if needed. In my company (18 user, 36 AD objects),  this is way more efficient then search for every single user.